# How to copy MySQL InnoDB database from Windows server to Ubuntu Linux server?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, innodb, database-migration

To upgrade our application deployment platform from **`Windows`** to **`Ubuntu Linux Server`**, we need copy a **`MySQL InnoDB database`** from Windows to Linux server, and I tried 2 ways to do it:

1, use **`mysqldump`** tool to export to a sql and then import it from Linux server, this way got a lot of problems, like Chinese character garbage and InnoDB type tables are incorrect.

2, directly **`copy`** the database file (under **`mysql/data/`**) to Linux MySQL data folder (**`/var/lib/mysql/`**), and restart the MySQL, and by typing command lines, I can see the database we copied, and can see all the tables in the database, but when I type command line '**`select * from sample_table`**', it shows error '**`ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'sampleSchema.sample_table' doesn't exist`**', I know this table really exists. I don't why this happened.

So hope anybody knows this gives me help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you can access your Ubuntu Server remotely from your windows pc, you can use [MySQL Workbench 5.2](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Comment: Thanks. I am not able to do this because of Ubuntu Linux server can be accessed by localhost for security reason. If this way is very likely to help me solve the problem I will ask my manager to allow it.

Comment: Of course. MySQL workbench is the new tool for MySQL design aside from phpmyadmin. They have this very new feature in data migration.

Comment: Ok. I'm assigned the permission to set the MySQL, so I comment the config 'bind-address  =127.0.0.1' in '/etc/mysql/my.cnf', and restart the MySQL, and then I want to grand previleges to users like typing grand all privileges on  *.*  to root@'%', it always show error: use near 'grand all privileges on  *.*  to root@'%' at line 1, how do I do?

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Sorry, this command line is wrong. Right is grant all privileges on *.* to root@IP identified by 'password' .

Comment: Where the error came from? You can use the IP address of your remote server then, login as root and password.

Comment: ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'sample_db.sample_table' doesn't exist

Comment: Why sample_db? you should create a new connection not an existing one and use your login credentials. Here's the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-server-startup-tab.html)